# Cordova/phonegap Sqlite transaction not executing properly

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, visual-studio-cordova

i want to fill multiple drop down using Cordova/phonegap, but below code for transaction doesn't execute properly.

Only first method for drop-down is executed properly while rest is skipped.
the function with `prefix:WriteToFill` is the function to append result to respective drop-down.

Please suggest me how to fill all drop-down.

```
initializeDropdown: function (callback) {
        var self = this;
        this.db = window.openDatabase("DemoDB", "1.0", "Demo DB", 4 * 1024 * 1024);

        this.db.transaction(function (tx) {

            var sql = "select M_ID,M_name from Tbl_Manager";
            tx.executeSql(sql, [], function (tx, results) {
                debugger;
                WriteToFillManager(results);
            });

            var sql2 = "select CC_ID,CC_NAME from Tbl1";
            tx.executeSql(sql2, [], function (tx, results2) {
                debugger;
                WriteToFillTbl1(results2);
            });

            var sql3 = "select C_ID,C_NAME from Tbl_cust";
            tx.executeSql(sql3, [], function (tx, results3) {
                debugger;
                WriteToFillCustomer(results3);

            });

            var sql4 = "select CURRENCY_ID,CURRENCY_CODE from Tbl_Currency";
            tx.executeSql(sql4, [], function (tx, results4) {
                debugger;
                WriteToFillCurrency(results4);

            });
        });

    },
```

Comment: Could you please add the error handler function into your `executeSql` see [document](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) and debug to see what error did you get?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion